# Java problem with high CPU running Universal Media Server

Tags: 18.04, java, cpu-load, mediaserver

I have used Universal Media Server for many years to stream family photos, home videos, music and movies to smart TV from desktop PC running Ubuntu (now on Bionic 18.04). The media library is very large.

I'm getting massive CPU usage caused by Oracle Java 8.  It can be as much as 40%.

UMS shows a lot of media indexing going on and I cannot close UMS via the interface.

My only resort is to use System Monitor to KILL Java.

Answer (score 2):

No idea how this occurred but a database file:

```
medias.mv.db
```

found in

```
/home/USERNAME/.config/UMS/database
```

had become massive, nearly 6GB.

I deleted the folder which UMS later recreated for me. The database file is now just over 1MB.

UMS and Java are now all happy and my home streaming is fab once more. Bliss.